# Futuristic novel where cats are telepathic and can detect liars and criminals

Tags: story-identification, novel, urban-fantasy

I'm looking for a novel set in the future (2036? date is mentioned on cover) and there's a picture of a cat on the cover.

It is about cats who are telepathic and can detect liars and criminals. The main characters are women who own the cats. Houses are run by computers linked to the owners; they show person's health and whether they're at home. No individual cars owned, they call up a communal car to travel.

Comment: Interesting, check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Finder's Seekers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/591805.Finders_Seekers) by Gayle Greeno?

> Their technological resources destroyed, a colonizing expedition from
>   Earth has been stranded on the world of Methuen for over two hundred
>   years. Their continued survival is largely due to the organization of
>   healers known as the Eumedicos and to the Seekers Veritas, a unique
>   group composed of pairs of Bondmates, one human and one ghatti—a
>   telepathic catlike being native to Methuen who bonds with a specific
>   human for life. These Bondmates travel from town to town, settling
>   disputes by truth-reading the minds and emotions of plaintiffs and
>   defendants. While most people respect the Seekers, there are those who
>   fear the ghatti powers. And now someone has begun attacking Seeker
>   pairs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  but this isn't the book I'm after. It is set on a future Earth. Joan

Comment: @joan - Have you looked through the checklist [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267)? Because you didn't mention that in your original question....